# Local and convective acceleration in 'water tank-pipe' systems

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acceleration, convection

I found this elegant solution to the Euler equation when the classic 'water tank-pipe' system opens the valve - the initial unsteady flow "stabilizes" and the equation turns into the Bernouli equation.

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/2-25-advanced-fluid-mechanics-fall-2013/1ff7ec3782567cdcedabdfd4b95c1792_MIT2_25F13_Unstea_Bernou.pdf

It looks as if the local acceleration term disappeared and only the convective acceleration term remained.
Of course, we maintain this assumption of relatively constant pressure in the tank and there and fluid is non viscous.

What would the situation of two tanks connected be like?
What would the equations of fluid motion in the pipe look like? Especially how to take into account convective acceleration and local acceleration?